# How do you come up with an efficient parser for a non-typical file format?

Tags: java, parsing

I am attempting to parse the following lines that are saved inside a file, and as you can see not in the typical file format.
What would be the best parser to come up with for such file with the following lines contained? The file name is file.make

```
[Silver: 9]
[Gold: 2]
[Utilize 2x Bolt to Helicopter until 10s] 
[Utilize 5x Ruler with 3x Bolt to Car until 7s] 
[Utilize Boat until 5s] 
[Utilize Tank until 4s] 
[Utilize 1x Paint with 2x Bolt with 5x Wrench to Motorcycle until 6s]
```

One thing I am noticing is that after the word 'Utilize' follows the number of tool/or tools and their name/names, the word 'with' is followed by another tool
the word 'to' is followed by a vehicle, and last the word 'until' is followed by time. Gold and silver just represent costs.

Comment: why should we solve your problem? SO is a board for help if you are stuck, not to help you from scratch. What have you tried so far? Why didnt it work? To lead you into a direction : use regex

Comment: For parsing a non-typical format of text, Use Regex as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You should take great care not to allow process bleed-through. Your comments *the word 'Utilize' follows the number of tool/or tools* suggest you are already doing that.

Bleed-over is when you attempt to do more than one thing with the data at the same time - in your case parsing **and** interpretation.

In your case I would suggest:

1. Split it into lines.
2. Make sure each line is surrounded by "[]" and remove them (or whatever).
3. Split the line into words.
4. Scan each word to see if they are special (e.g. with, of, until).
5. Attempt interpretation of the words.

Make sure you perform each of the above functions **separately**. Do not try to jump ahead.

Comment: Thank you so much on the guidance! What method do you advise I use for the steps you suggested? A few members are recommending Regex.

Comment: @OM - Each stage I mentioned would use it's own technique - you may find a RegEx useful for stage 3 (although `String.split` would probably do fine) but the others could use simple string functions.

Answer (score 0):

there are tools that can create a parser automatically for you, if you supply them with the grammar rules. [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is one example.

however, it is up to you to define the grammar or deduct the the grammar rules from an existing example, for the example you supplied it would be something like:

```
S -> RESOURCE: INTEGER
RESOURCE -> Silver, Gold
INTEGER -> [1..1024]
```